# Change spacing when new class is created in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

If you create a new PHP class using `CMD + N` template, it creates a new PHP file with the following structure:

[image]

Notice that by default it places 2 spaces after `<?php` and 2 after `namespace` declaration. This is way too much for an empty class. Is there a preferences input I can set so that only 1 space is inserted after `namespace` declaration and zero after `<?php`?

This are my partial config PHP settings. None of the options seems to work.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to File | Settings | Editor | File and Code Templates and edit new lines in "PHP Class" template.